# sqliteexception no such column on galaxy s2 even if the columns are present

Tags: android, sqlite

on the emulator, this code works with no bugs or exceptions:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), "body = ? and date = ?", new String[]{body,date)});
```

the sms is correctly deleted.

But when I try this on galaxy s2, I have an sqliteexception no such column.

I checked with :

```
Cursor columns = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,null,null,null);
    for (int i=0;i<columns.getColumnCount();i++){
        Log.i("name", columns.getColumnName(i));
    }
```

if the columns were there and it was the case, they were all present. It should have worked ass well on  the galaxy s2 like on the emulator. I don't know if this works or is the same on other devices. but from where is this exception coming from?

here is the exception log :

```
02-07 20:44:32.364: E/AndroidRuntime(14658): 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: body: , 
while compiling: SELECT _id FROM threads WHERE _id IN (SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM
sms WHERE (body = ? and date = ?) UNION SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM wpm WHERE 
(body = ? and date = ?) UNION SELECT DISTINCT thread_id FROM pdu WHERE ( locked = 1 
AND body = ? and date = ?))
```

and here the returned columns for "content://sms" with cursor :

```
02-07 20:53:21.045: W/KeyCharacterMap(14961): No keyboard for id 0
02-07 20:53:21.060: W/KeyCharacterMap(14961): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-07 20:53:26.045: I/ApplicationPackageManager(14961): cscCountry is not German : FTM
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): _id
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): thread_id
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): address
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): person
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): date
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): protocol
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): read
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): status
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): type
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): reply_path_present
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): subject
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): body
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): service_center
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): locked
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): error_code
02-07 20:53:26.320: I/name(14961): seen
02-07 20:53:26.325: I/name(14961): deletable
02-07 20:53:26.325: I/name(14961): hidden
02-07 20:53:26.325: I/name(14961): group_id
02-07 20:53:26.325: I/name(14961): group_type
02-07 20:53:26.325: I/name(14961): delivery_date
```

Comment: Are you sure galaxy s2 has same content provider column? I suspect not. I would print out meta data of the uri you are trying to query to make sure column exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having the same scenario the Message gets deleted on emulator ,My Htc Desire,Galaxy Mini, But throws exception on Galaxy S,Galaxy SL

This is what I have done for now .. will Improve/update my answer ..as current implementation is working fine

```
try
            {

                Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
                int i= getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, "address=? and date=?", new String[] {Phone, Time});
                Log.d("*****GE *********", Phone +" "+ Time + "  ^^"+i);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d("deleteEx", ex.toString());
                Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
                int i= getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, "address=? and date=?", new String[] {Phone, Time});
                Log.d("*****GE *********", Phone +" "+ Time + "  ^^"+i);
            }
            finally
            {

                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.nothing, R.anim.animout);}
```

I have put the code in try catch..I try it first Time if its throws exception i do the same in catch and it works.
Hope it helps.
I am not a pro .. so i do not know the reason why this is happening

Comment: yes I don't know the reason eather, it must be a stange bug with samsung galaxy phones.